# Hive sum(column1 * column2) Issue

Tags: apache, hive, hiveql

Hive version : 1.0

```
select SUM(table.quantity * table.our_price) from table;
```

This simple query fails with this error,

> Diagnostic Messages for this Task: Error: java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive Runtime Error
>   while processing row (tag=0) [Error getting row data with exception
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:310)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:215)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:353)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:353)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:197)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:183)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:248)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:455)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)  ]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:265)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:455)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166) Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Hive
>   Runtime Error while processing row (tag=0) [Error getting row data
>   with exception java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:310)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:215)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:353)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.buildJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:353)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:197)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeUtils.getJSONString(SerDeUtils.java:183)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:248)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:455)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:397)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:172)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1657)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:166)  ]
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:253)
>           ... 7 more Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:791)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.mr.ExecReducer.reduce(ExecReducer.java:244)
>           ... 7 more Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.readVInt(LazyBinaryUtils.java:310)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryUtils.checkObjectByteInfo(LazyBinaryUtils.java:215)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.parse(LazyBinaryStruct.java:142)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.LazyBinaryStruct.getField(LazyBinaryStruct.java:199)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazybinary.objectinspector.LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.getStructFieldData(LazyBinaryStructObjectInspector.java:64)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeColumnEvaluator._evaluate(ExprNodeColumnEvaluator.java:98)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:77)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.ExprNodeEvaluator.evaluate(ExprNodeEvaluator.java:65)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.updateAggregations(GroupByOperator.java:597)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processAggr(GroupByOperator.java:888)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processKey(GroupByOperator.java:718)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.GroupByOperator.processOp(GroupByOperator.java:786)
>           ... 8 more

I dont get much from this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess from "ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException" that you might have NULL, empty in table.quantity and table.price, or that the sum result is too big. If the SUM is too big you should cast your value to bigint :

```
SELECT CAST(SUM(table.quantity * table.our_price) AS bigint) FROM table;
```

Comment: It still does not help. If I do a separate "select sum(our_price),sum(quantity) from table" it works fine....

Comment: thanks for the tip...I think it works select sum(cast(quantity as biging) * our_price) from table";